# What is the use of converting the array to a string in this line "System.out.println(new String(array1));"

Tags: java

This program is taken from the text book I use to teach the students with. In the last line of the code I do not understand what the author was trying to say new String(array2). I get the same output without the new String i.e. printing directly array2.

```
public class ArrayCopyDemo
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        char [] array1 = 

        {'d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'};
        char [] array2 = new char[15];

        System.arraycopy(array1, 3, array2, 0, 7);
        System.out.println(new String(array2));  
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no use at all. The `println(char[])` overload exists precisely for this purpose.

Comment: thank you - Andy Turner, but if I were to give an explanation to the students telling them why it is there in the text book, what possible explanation I can give to them?

Comment: probably the person writing this wasn't aware of the println overload, but was aware that array doesn't have a toString override. even people writing textbooks are not experts in every little detail, and don't have to be.

Comment: @WellieNelson I'd ask them to explain to you whether there is any difference. It'd be an exercise in learning to find and understand documentation.

Comment: The only advantage I can think of is converting it to a string could let you do other string like operations such as doing something like:

`System.out.println("New array: " + new String(array1));  `

Comment: @Nathan Hughes - Thank you for pointing that out. That is actually my mistake. I was trying to do something with the code, and changed it. I'll correct it here as well

Comment: @Everyone - thank you so much for the clarifications. I think my doubt is cleared now.

Answer (score 2):

Evidently the person writing this knew about arrays not overriding toString. We've all been burned by that one, it only takes once printing out something and getting a hashcode back to make the point.

But maybe the writer didn't know that println has an override for char[]; I know I was not aware of it until a few minutes ago. You can do a lot of Java programming without ever needing that. If you in fact don't know about that then it would make sense to do the conversion explicitly like the posted code.

(Or just as likely, it could be the author did know but didn't want to assume his students knew about it. When you write code meant for beginners to read you want to avoid confusing the reader with anything unusual, if only to avoid having to field the same newbie questions over and over.)

If the question is how to explain this to students, you may want to talk about how in software everything is changing all the time, and our objective is to make working software on time pressure that is good enough even though our knowledge is imperfect.

There's also an opportunity to talk about the ramifications of design decisions, comparing how in Java we have a differentiation between Strings and char arrays, and primitives and objects, unlike say in Haskell. So we have these design choices that cause odd corner cases and ugliness in the API, and the Java implementors can't just get rid of this cruft because of their concern for backward compatibility. Java is full of unintuitive edge cases, see [Bloch and Gafter's puzzle book](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/).

Often teachers (specifically grad students) are put in a situation where on short notice they have to teach a language that they've never used before. Textbook writers are working to get their book finished and may miss something occasionally. Sometimes the language has bizarre edge cases that it's not fair to expect everybody to know. Students have to adjust their expectations to these realities.

Comment: Thank you, explanation/advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful in case your are concatenating it with a string. Ex:-

```
char [] array1 = 

        {'d','e','f','g','h','i'};
        char [] array2 = new char[15];

        System.arraycopy(array1, 3, array2, 0, 7);
        System.out.println(new String(array1));
```

If You were to print  **Something** `array1`content. Say "**Hello defghi**"

> Incorrect Code

```
System.out.println("Something"+array1)); //"Something 'array type' as string and char array is being concatenated.
```

> Correct code

```
 System.out.println("Something"+new String(array1));
```

It's an example to show the use. Although the use of `new String()` is of no significance in your code.

Comment: `System.out.println("Something"+array1));` does not throw an exception like you are stating in your answer. It is printing the hash of the object appended to the string.

Comment: Yeah true. My bad

Answer (score 0):

In generall, `new String(array2)` is used to convert a `char[]` array into a `String`, with the same characters as in the array itsself.

Note that there are two overloaded variants of the `println` method defined, see `java.io.PrintStream.println(char[] x)` and `java.io.PrintStream.println(String x)`, however, they result in the same behaviour, so you could omit the `new String` creation.

However, you should be aware of the difference.